# Hadoop Eclipse Plugin Erros in Ubuntu

Tags: hadoop, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to build some program on hadoop with ubuntu. I am able to successfully install and run hadoop on my machine in pseudo-distributed mode. But when I tried to use eclipse-plugin for making project,I am facing several issue. After putting parameters for connecting to the server in the eclipse plugin I am getting the following error:

1.Error: java.io.IOException:Unknown Protocol to jobTracker:org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.Protocol.ClientProtocol

I am using hadoop 0.20 version and eclipse plugin is also from the configuration directory. Any suggestion or reason why these errors are coming.And what can I do for build hadoop project on eclipse?

[image: These are the errros that are coming]

Comment: see if this link helps. i have outlined the procedure here. http://cloudfront.blogspot.in/2012/07/how-to-run-mapreduce-programs-using.html

Comment: I will now try the way u explained in the tutorial but I do have one confusion with my lack of knowledge of java environment. Actually in my /usr/lib/jvm. I do have two java folder one is java-7-oracle and other is jdk1.7.0. Till now I was using jdk1.7.0. Can u tell me are both can be used or there might be some differences in these pacakages? And how do I know, exactly was version of java eclipse is using?

Comment: Ubuntu comes with it's own pre-installed jvm(the openjdk). but it is advisable to use sun java(now oracle) when you are working with hadoop. so you should give "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle" as your JAVA_HOME. you can choose which java to use by using : sudo update-alternatives --config java

Answer (score -1):

Go to "Edit hadoop location".

Switch Map/Reduce Master port with DFS master port.